# How to operate atomic struct in two different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, memory, atomic

The code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

struct Field
{
    int px1{0};
    int px2{0};
};
std::atomic<Field> data;

void process()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        //Have problem with the following three lines
        auto tmp = data.load(std::memory_order_consume);
        tmp.px1++;
        data.store(tmp, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

int main()
{
    using ThreadPtr = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>;
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>, 2> ths;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        ths[i] = ThreadPtr(new std::thread(process));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        ths[i]->join();
    }

    std::cout << "result: " << data.load().px1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to operate the struct in two different threads, considering the efficiency, I don't want to use the std::mutex, so I call to mind the atomic. The struct field is lock-free.
In theory, the efficiency should be good.

The question: how to make sure the result is 20000 without using mutex?

Comment: A bit of general advice: if you're not capable without help to write lock-free code, then don't write lock-free code and just use a mutex. I say this not to be mean, but because lock-free code can be wrong in very subtle ways, and writing it correctly requires serious expertise.

Comment: Thanks, man, but I need to learn how to write lock-free code, because my work need low latency code ...

Answer (score 2):

First, atomics aren't necessarily faster or better than mutex - only when used correctly in the right circumstances. Locking a mutex is a quick operation aside from possible waiting and the acquire/release memory fences on locking/unlocking - which cause other portions of code to slowdown due to loss of cached data. For some unclear reason you use `release` and `acquire` fences in the example- `relaxed` should've been more than sufficient in the case.

Second, in this example, a single threaded program will operate faster if you ditch all atomics and multi-threading operations regardless of how many threads you use.

Also, why `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>` and `new std::thread`? Why the unnecessary indirection with `unique_ptr`? Just use `std::thread`.

Now to the main question. There are operations like `fetch_add` that allow atomic level addition on integers but they do not allow custom operations on atomics.

To allow a custom modification one generally needs to load the current state, modify it, and then save modified data. Since the data could be modified between load and save the save is conditional - do it only if it matches with pre-modified state. If it fails retry or whatever else you decide.

There are atomic operations that do what I said with some minor differences: `compare_exchange_strong` / `compare_exchange_weak`. Strong version fails only when a modification was made while weak might fail spuriously. Generally, it is recommended to use weak version as the strong version is typically just a looped weak version.

See [cppreference/compare_exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) for examples and documentation.